# Where is the temp file of recorder in Android?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, file-system, samsung-galaxy-note-2, voice-recording, temp-files

Galaxy Note2 4.3 Samsung firmware.

Recording for 1 hour with the highest quality, accidentally pressed "back" button, nothing saved.
Usually the file would be saved automatically even if "back" is pressed. But maybe 1 hour is too big for the simple recorder app.

Any chance that there is a tmp file somewhere?
Or recorder just stores everything in DRAM before hitting save button?(that would be too naive..)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's on main drive of your phone (at lest it was in my case), named something like .voice.3ga

Just plug in your phone to PC, an run search for .3ga file type.

Hope this helps.